# Application pool crash on windows 2012 IIS 8.0 server

Tags: asp.net, .net, sybase, windows-server-2012, iis-8

we are seeing  following error in event logs after app pool crash once in a day. I am trying to understand what is the cause. Can some one advise.

```
Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: cb7c6f90-419d-11e5-9417-005056935d0b
Report Status: 4
Hashed bucket: "
Error 8/13/2015 5:29:29 AM Application Error 1000 (100) "Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108835
Faulting module name: sybdrvado20.dll, version: 2.157.1300.0, time stamp: 0x53c85084
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x0000000000007c32
Faulting process id: 0x1c68
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0d59b5268bfa1
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\TEMP\Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.64bits.4.157.1300.0\sybdrvado20.dll
Report Id: cb7c6f90-419d-11e5-9417-005056935d0b
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID: "
```

Comment: obviously something to do with your sybase database...

Comment: I understand its sybase dll issue. what is the issue with it is the question .

Comment: It is impossible to tell what's the cause except Sybase related. So you will have to collect more data probably with the help from Sybase technical support.